# Getting Logs from child project created in Jenkins Parameterized Build Plugin for Email Ext plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

I have successfully created parent child project in Jenkins using Parameterized Build Plugin but the problem i faced is when i am attaching logs to our team whenever a build fail.

The email-ext plugin is sending email with build log of parent project which is just a calling project and not the logs of child project.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? I am in this exact situation!

Comment: not yet. I have changed my strategy by using individual project now instead of parent child project :(

Comment: Have you tried setting up the email on the child project instead of the parent? That way it should pick up the right log. Have not tried this yet though.

Comment: Thanks, The solution won't work in my situation as i was having multiple childs with same parent. So for example i have a child project doing build and other is doing deployment [optionally i can have third to do static code review [like fxcop etc]]. So in child it's not feasible for me to generate emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i got the solution. 
I need to discard the Pramaeterized plugin but now is using the Build flow Plugin [https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin]

The benefit is it is giving me the log to be placed in the parent job without any modification in the child project.

the usage is as follows:

```
def today = new Date()
out.println '----------------- Build Started At '+ today+ '----------------------------'
b=build("<BaseBuild>",ParentWorkSpace:build.properties["workspace"],Param:"Value")
today=new Date()
out.println '--------       Build Log    --------------   '
out.println b.log
out.println '----------------- Build Ended At '+ today+ '----------------------------'
```

This way i have full control and when i attach the log then i am attaching the original log in my email :)

I hope it will help many.